# Redshift - Retrieving SQL used to create a view

Tags: view, amazon-redshift

I have mistakenly deleted a table and hence the view that was dependent on it is lost. I am trying to re-create this view but I am not sure what was the SQL used for this.

I have tried the below but each of the these give me partial SQL statement and not the complere SQL used to create the view.

```
select starttime, type, text from svl_statementtext
where lower(text) like '%view_name%' order by starttime desc;


select query, text
from stl_querytext
where pid = pg_backend_pid() and lower(text) like '%view_name%'
order by query desc;
```

Comment: have you tried stl_ddltext ?

Comment: @JonScott, thanks was able to fix this..